# ¿Cómo buscar por código los datos guardados en un archivo TXT?

Tags: java, txt

Tengo un archivo de texto que contiene datos en este formato, mi problema es que no sé cómo buscar por el código los datos que necesito.

```
   código  nombre   apellido    DNI    usuario
1. 200   | marcos | ramirez  |1425765| ramirez @gmail.com
2. 150   | maria  | lopez    |3266547| mari @gmail.com
```

Por ejemplo, al buscar el código 150 debería mostrar toda la línea:

```
código  nombre   apellido    DNI    usuario
150   | maria  | lopez    |3266547| mari @gmail.com
```

Hasta el momento he intentado esto, sin embargo no tengo claro cómo es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

```java
    public void buscar(int cod){

        Vector cab=new Vector();
            //Se crea un vector que tenga código, nombre, apellido, DNI, Usuario
            cab.addElement("codigo");
            cab.addElement("nombre");
            cab.addElement("apellido");
            cab.addElement("DNI");
            cab.addElement("Usuario");
            int codi = cod;

            // Se empieza a leer el archivo y se busca el código
            try
            {
                BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Alumnos.txt"));
                // PrintStream ps=new PrintStream();
                String d="";
                // Mientras aún hayan líneas por leer
                while((d=br.readLine())!=null){
                    if (d.indexOf(codi)!=-1) {
                        // Aquí tengo el problema, pues esta condición me resulta errónea
                    }
                       
                }
                    
            }catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
```

¿Cómo podría lograr entonces leer y obtener las líneas por el código?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Comment: quiero saber como  buscar por código los datos que guarde en un archivo txt  y mostrarlos por una tabla. Y tambien saber que le falta a mi codigo?

Comment: Plantea una estrategia para leer el dato código .

Answer (score 2):

Para mejorar la estructura del código un poco.

1. Vamos a definir una clase que tenga las propiedades de tu objeto
2. Vamos a definir una clase que lea el archivo y lo interprete
3. Vamos a hacer manejo de [excepciones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

   - [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)
   - [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)
   - [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

### **Código**

**Clase del estudiante**

```java
public class Student {
    int code;
    String name;
    String lastname;
    int DNI;
    String user;

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public Student setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
        return this;
    }

    public Student setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Student setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
        return this;
    }

    public Student setDni(int DNI) {
        this.DNI = DNI;
        return this;
    }

    public Student setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return code + "\t|\t" + name  + "\t|\t" + lastname + "\t|\t" + DNI + "\t|\t" + user + "\n";
    }

}
```

*Notas:*

1. Esta clase hace uso de [BuilderPattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-pattern-in-java/) para mejorar la legibilidad del código. Como verás, el diseño [BuilderPattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-pattern-in-java/), lo puedes ver como setters de un objeto común y corriente, sólo que estos sí retornan algo. ¿Qué cosa? el contexto en el que están (el mismo Objeto).
2. Se [sobrescribe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) el método `toString` (método que tienen todos los objetos en Java). Esto con la finalidad de mostrar mejor y más fácilmente el resultado. Bien una manera sencilla es [sobrescribir el método `toString`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/), bien podrías definir otro método como se muestra abajo

```java
public String formatStudent(){
    return code + "\t|\t" + name  + "\t|\t" + lastname + "\t|\t" + DNI + "\t|\t" + user + "\n";
}
```

**Clase para leer e interpretar el archivo**

```java
public class CustomClass {

    final static short BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    private static void printRows(final String file_path){
        File file2read = new File(file_path);
        // Verifica que el archivo exista
        if (!file2read.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Could not find file \"" + file2read.getName() + "\", absolute path: \"" + file2read.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
            return;
        }
        // Verifica que el archivo sea un archivo (que no sea una carpeta por ejemplo)
        if (!file2read.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("\"" + file2read.getName() + "\" is NOT a file absolute path: \"" + file2read.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
            return;
        }
        // Verifica que tengas permisos de lectura sobre el archivo
        if (!file2read.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("\"" + file2read.getName() + "\" exists but do not have read permission, absolute path: \"" + file2read.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
            return;
        }

        readWithBufferedReader(file2read, 200, 201);
    }

    public static void readWithBufferedReader(final File file2read, int... codes) {

        StringBuilder strOutBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        
        try (BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2read), BUFFER_SIZE)) {
            // headers
            strOutBuilder.append(buffReader.readLine()).append('\n');
            do {
                line = buffReader.readLine();

                if (line == null)
                    break;

                try {
                    Student student = parseLine(line);
                    if (Arrays.stream(codes).anyMatch(c -> c == student.getCode()))
                        strOutBuilder.append(student.toString());
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.err.printf("%s %s %s\n", "The line \"", line, "\" couldn't be parsed");
                }

            } while (line.length() > 0);

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Something went really really wrong!!");
            ex.printStackTrace(); // Only for debugging
        }

        System.out.println(strOutBuilder.toString());
    }

    /**
     * @param line row read from document with expected format: code | name | lastname | DNI | User
     * @return Student
     * @throws NumberFormatException if code or DNI aren't integers
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if column doesn't have the expected format
     */
    public static Student parseLine(String line) throws NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException {

        String[] data = line.split("\\|", 5);

        if (data.length != 5)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("line couldn't be parsed");

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setCode(parseInt(data[0].trim()))
            .setName(data[1].trim())
            .setLastname(data[2].trim())
            .setDni(parseInt(data[3].trim()))
            .setUser(data[4].trim());

        return student;
    }
    // Si el String que pasas por argumento no es un número entero, entonces se avienta la excepción
    public static int parseInt(String number) throws NumberFormatException{
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
    }
}
```

*Notas:*

1. Para tu [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-int-) se define un tamaño de buffer de 1024 bytes
2. Se agregan validaciones a tu archivo, tal como: si existe realmente, si es un archivo y si tienes permisos de lectura sobre él
3. Se hace uso de [varargs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/) para poder obtener varios alumnos según sus códigos. Estos son bastante útiles, los puedes imaginar como si fuera un arreglo. y se pueden recibir *n* argumentos, por lo que resulta muy útil en este caso.
4. Se hace uso de [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para mejorar la creación dinámica de Strings, esto para mejorar el rendimiento del programa. Puedes imaginarlo como un String, solamente que este está especialmente diseñado para poder hacer operaciones de concatenación.
5. Se avientan las excepciones antes mencionadas en los métodos `parseInt` y `parseLine` y son atrapadas en el método `readWithBufferedReader`
6. Como se ve en esta línea `readWithBufferedReader(file2read, 200, 201);` se mandan a imprimir los estudiantes con código 200 y 201 del archivo que se le pasa por argumento.
7. Se hace uso de la función [anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), de la clase Stream, esto para saber si existe el alumno con alguno de los códigos recibidos por parámetros; esto es algo ya más avanzado, por lo que si no quieres usar este tipo de funciones de Java, puedes crear un método que simule lo que hace `anyMatch`

```java
 public static boolean anyMatch(int code, int... codes){
    for (int c : codes) {
        if (c == code) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### **Ejemplo completo**

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CustomClass.printRows("Students.txt");

    }

    private static class Student {
        int code;
        String name;
        String lastname;
        int DNI;
        String user;

        public int getCode() {
            return this.code;
        }

        public Student setCode(int code) {
            this.code = code;
            return this;
        }

        public Student setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Student setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
            return this;
        }

        public Student setDni(int DNI) {
            this.DNI = DNI;
            return this;
        }

        public Student setUser(String user) {
            this.user = user;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return code + "\t|\t" + name  + "\t|\t" + lastname + "\t|\t" + DNI + "\t|\t" + user + "\n";
        }

    }

    private static class CustomClass {

        final static short BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

        private static void printRows(final String file_path){
            File file2read = new File(file_path);

            if (!file2read.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Could not find file \"" + file2read.getName() + "\", absolute path: \"" + file2read.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
                return;
            }

            if (!file2read.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("\"" + file2read.getName() + "\" is NOT a file absolute path: \"" + file2read.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
                return;
            }

            if (!file2read.canRead()) {
                System.out.println("\"" + file2read.getName() + "\" exists but do not have read permission, absolute path: \"" + file2read.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
                return;
            }

            readWithBufferedReader(file2read, 200, 201);
        }

        public static void readWithBufferedReader(final File file2read, int... codes) {

            StringBuilder strOutBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            try (BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2read), BUFFER_SIZE)) {
                // headers
                strOutBuilder.append(buffReader.readLine()).append('\n');
                do {
                    line = buffReader.readLine();

                    if (line == null)
                        break;

                    try {
                        Student student = parseLine(line);
                        if (Arrays.stream(codes).anyMatch(c -> c == student.getCode()))
                            strOutBuilder.append(student.toString());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        System.err.printf("%s %s %s\n", "The line \"", line, "\" couldn't be parsed");
                    }

                } while (line.length() > 0);

            } catch(IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Something went really really wrong!!");
                ex.printStackTrace(); // Only for debugging
            }

            System.out.println(strOutBuilder.toString());
        }

        /**
         * @param line row read from document with expected format: code | name | lastname | DNI | User
         * @return Student
         * @throws NumberFormatException if code or DNI aren't integers
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if column doesn't have the expected format
         */
        public static Student parseLine(String line) throws NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException {

            String[] data = line.split("\\|", 5);

            if (data.length != 5)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("line couldn't be parsed");

            Student student = new Student();
            student.setCode(parseInt(data[0].trim()))
                .setName(data[1].trim())
                .setLastname(data[2].trim())
                .setDni(parseInt(data[3].trim()))
                .setUser(data[4].trim());

            return student;
        }

        public static int parseInt(String number) throws NumberFormatException{
            return Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }

}
```

**Archivo**

```
código nombre   apellido    DNI      usuario
200 | marcos | ramirez  | 1425765 | ramirez@gmail.com
201 | maria  | lopez    | 3266547 | mari@gmail.com
202 | marta  | gomez    | 3266567 | matg@gmail.com
```

Output

```
código nombre   apellido    DNI      usuario
200 |   marcos  |   ramirez |   1425765 |   ramirez@gmail.com
201 |   maria   |   lopez   |   3266547 |   mari@gmail.com
```

Comment: Como comentario, si son muchas las cosas que propone mi respuesta, puedes cambiar el **BuilderPattern** por un **constructor**; cambiar la **función** `anyMatch` por un **método que te retorne un booleano** indicando si el código del estudiante está presente en los varargs; los **varargs** por un **arreglo** de enteros y lo demás te diría que es conveniente utilizarlo

Comment: Creo que a la hora de responder preguntas que son claramente de gente que está aprendiendo o haciendo tareas de clase, es muy importante intentar ceñirse a lo que hace referencia en la pregunta, y no añadirle complejidad. Es decir, si está intentando aprender a realizar bucles sencillos y a manejar un BufferedReader, empezar a meterle clases, streams, patrones de diseño, lambdas... lo mismo le explota la cabeza intentando entenderlo. A veces se nos olvida lo complicado que parece programar cuando no sabes casi nada, y respondemos con cosas demasiado complejas a preguntas MUY sencillas :)

Comment: Más que nada, las respuestas que escribo trato de hacerlas lo mejor posible, para que personas que en un futuro tengan la misma duda y tengan los conocimientos suficientes puedan usarla como referencia. Además trato de hacerlas lo más explicativas que puedo y aunque luego se me olvida, suelo comentar (si es el caso) que espero que la respuesta aunque complicada para quien preguntó sea algo que lo impulse a investigar más estos temas para que mejore sus habilidades y aprenda otras formas más "correctas" de solucionar los problemas